How to manage HA na d Horizontal Scaling of Ingress Gateway (FOR HTTP2/GRPC Scenarios)?
Request-based loadbalancing for the applications behind the Ingress Gateway would be taken care of by the Ingress gateway, but how to take care of loadbalancing the ingress gateway proxies itself for HTTP2/GRPC
If my understanding is correct, for ingress (proxy gateway), there would be proxy pods and typically a load balancer service in front exposes them externally.
The proxy pods could be scaled horizontally to handle the load and for HA. The Kubernetes service would take care of some basic load-balancing of the connections between multiple proxy(gateway) pods.
As load-balancing of Kubernetes services are on connections (L4 level) and not at the request level, I believe some ingress gateways/ L7 proxy or Service Mesh are used. How does one manage scaling and HA for these proxy pods(ingress gateway) when the type of requests is HTTP2/GRPC or even for HTTP1(Where Keep-Alive header is set) where clients keep reusing the same connection?
